# function within a function approach

Tags: javascript

Lately I came into something call functional programming, and I learn about call(),bind() and apply().. But I still don't quite get it because I never use functional programming approach in Javascript.

like function within a function

```
function checkGreater(limit){
    return function(limit, item){
        return item > limit;
    }.bind(this,limit);

}
```

It sounds to me it make things more complicated. When does we need a function within a function approach? like the above example code.

Comment: Well, when you have a higher order function that is supposed to return a new function, then you have to create that function inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Examples like this take advantage of JavaScript's closures to implement what is called a "factory". [Here's an article on MDN that discusses closures and factories](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
function checkGreater(limit) {
    return function(limit, item) {
        return item > limit;
    }.bind(this, limit);
}
```

In this example, this is a factory that returns a function which you can pass arguments to and checks whether the argument passed is greater than the limit passed to the factory. Here's example usage:

```
var greaterThanTen = checkGreater(10);
```

This returns:

```
function (10, item) {
    return item > 10;
}
```

and stores it to `greaterThanTen`. The first argument to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is called the calling context of the function, and in this simple example, it really doesn't matter what the context is since it's not being used, but can be referenced inside the function through use of the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

Then you can use `greaterThanTen` like this:

```
if (greaterThanTen(5)) {
    console.log('5 is greater than 10'); // never gets called
}

if (greaterThanTen(11)) {
    console.log('11 is greater than 10'); // this gets called
}
```

If I were to write my own factory to do this, however, I would probably write it like so:

```
function checkGreater(limit) {
    return function(item) {
        return item > this;
    }.bind(limit);
}
```

This does the exact same thing as the example above, except the factory makes use of the calling context of the inner function to set the limit.

Be aware that in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) this will work exactly as expected. However, in "loose" mode, `this` will be coerced to `new Number(limit)` which is not a primitive value and cannot be compared using the strict equality operator [`===`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). Thank you @FelixKling for reminding me of this pitfall.

Comment: In your factory, what would the this refer to?

Comment: @EltonJamie In the last example, `.bind()` binds `limit` to `this`, so `checkGreater(15)` would return a function with `15` binded to the `this` of the returned function.

Comment: Regarding binding `limit` to `this`: That only really works in strict mode. In "loose" mode, the value of `this` will be coerced to an object, which can lead to all kinds of other problems (well, mostly problems regarding equality comparison).

Comment: I don't think that is functional programming, for me it's like adding complexity to a simple method.

Comment: @EltonJamie The example you provided is extremely simplified to demonstrate what's going on. There are a lot more involved situations in which this technique provides a major benefit and simplification to the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling I just ran a `checkEqual` factory (hopefully you can gather what I mean from the name) in loose mode and it had no problems checking the equality of a `number` type. Can you provide some evidence to the problems you're refering to in loose mode? The only problem I recall is if you try to bind something like `null` or `undefined` to `this` and loose mode coerces it to `window`.

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, I see what you mean now. I was using loose equality operator, not strict equality. Thanks for clarifying.